# bootstrap order on mobile screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Hello everyone and 'happy' easter.

I am setting up my bootstrap. The layout is fine when I have on a computer screen and ipad. But when I minimize to mobile size, the 'left panel' is the first which appears. I would like that to go under the 'right sidepanel'

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3sdd95cs/)

Does anybody knows how I can do that?

```
<?php
if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();
?>
<?php include dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).'/resources/includes/header.html'; ?>

<div class="row" style="border: 2px solid blue; height: 100vh;">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="border: 2px solid red; height: 100%;">
        Left Sidenpanel

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8" style="border: 2px solid red;height: 100%;">
        Left Sidepanel button
        <div class="row" style="border: 2px solid green;height: 20vh;">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            Insert
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="border: 2px solid green;height: 60vh;">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row" style="border: 2px solid green">
                    <div class="col-md-1" style="border: 2px solid purple; height: 100%;">
                        Latest
                    </div>                      
                    <div class="col-md-8" style="border: 2px solid purple;height: 100%;">
                        Some Content
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-md-1" style="border: 2px solid purple; height: 100%;">
                        Right 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1" style="border: 2px solid purple; height: 100%;">
                        Right 2
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-md-1" style="border: 2px solid purple; height: 100%;">
                        Right 3
                    </div>                          
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="border: 2px solid black;height: 15vh;">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-3" style="border: 2px solid purple; height: 100%;">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" style="border: 2px solid purple; height: 100%;">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" style="border: 2px solid purple; height: 100%;">
                    3
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" style="border: 2px solid purple; height: 100%;">
                    4
                </div>

            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="border: 2px solid red;height: 100%;">
        Right Sidepanel
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 2px solid red;height: 100%;">
        <?php include dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).'/resources/includes/footer.html'; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your classes,  add "col-sm-* (table position you want").  Sm is for smartphone ! Md is for Middle Display and Lg is for Large Display.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I know how to split the sm up, so I can order them? Everything else is looking fine, except the left panel. So it is only the left panel i want in the bootom

Comment: Try to add offset ! Like "co-sm-offset-*"